# How to change margins in a thesis template?

Tags: margins, templates

I'm using an online available LaTeX template for my PhD thesis. 
In the template, the margins are the following:

```
 \setmarginsrb           {1.5in}  % left margin
                         {0.6in}  % top margin
                         {1.0in}  % right margin
                         {0.8in}  % bottom margin
                         {20pt}  % head height
                         {0.25in}  % head sep
                         {9pt}  % foot height
                         {0.3in}  % foot sep
```

As requested by my University, the margins have to be:

> Inside margins: 40mm
>   Top and Outside margins: 15mm
>   Bottom margins: 20mm

How do the template margins have to be modified in order to address the University request?

Comment: Can you please give us more informations? What thesis template do you use? Link? It seems this thesis uses an own macro to define the margins. How does it work? BTW: in inner margin of 4 cm = 40 mm is very large. Then you should use an outer margin of 2*4cm = 8cm. Strange typography, very strange ...

Comment: I agree with Kurt, those are horrible margin-values! Are you sure they are correct?

Comment: Hi, this settings look familiar to me. I don't remember where the template were, but it was horrible. Any chance you can using something like plain `report` or `memoir` or KOMAs `scrreprt` as a base for your thesis? We all will have less trouble that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would replace the `\setmarginsrb{}` with the `\usepackage{geometry}`, see more [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

Something like this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
letterpaper, % a4paper
left=   40 mm,
right=  40 mm,
top=    15 mm,
bottom= 20 mm,
}
```

You can also specify `inner` and `outer` margins with package `geometry`

Assuming I am interpreting your university's guidelines correct, maybe that is the real issue, that their guidelines are unclear.

Comment: The template is using a different method to set the margins; generally it's best to only use one method otherwise conflicts can arise. Also your method will not handle inner/outer margins as specified.

Comment: @PaulGessler, good point. I did imagine that the `\usepackage{geometry}` would replace the `\setmarginsrb`. Maybe the university should be consulted, I for one do not understand how to interpret their guidelines. @elb, maybe you could post a link to the template in question?

Comment: What is there to interpret? It's very clear: inner margin `40mm`, outer and top margins `15mm`, and bottom margin `20mm`.

Comment: @PaulGessler, I am obviously in over my head when it comes to the typographical lingo. Please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: You can specify `inner` and `outer` margins with package `geometry`. That will give the expected result no matter if printed `oneside` or `twoside`.

Comment: Your quotes were messed up a bit, i corrected this. Also deleted my name. We can savely delete my comments ;-)